# How to create a game engine for android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, game-engine

I am new to android development and I plan to make a 2d game engine but I don't really know where to start. I read something on the internet but I don't find any good opengl es documentation for android, I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no idea where to start, I will point you to the excellent book [Beginning Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430246774). If you are serious about this, then it is more than worth the investment.

This is a beginner/intermediate text, but in the book the authors (Mario Zechner & Robert Green) create a fairly decent game development framework - not exactly a fully blown engine but it is highly reusable and easily expandable and, unless you've created a game engine before, I would advise you to walk before you try running. Creating a game engine is very complicated so start off with something that you will be able to finish and use, then once you've got that down you will have the confidence you need to build your own.

For me this book was the perfect introduction to android development - I had a great deal of programming experience but mostly in C/C++ with DirectX, some basic OpenGL, and software rendering and had no knowledge of Android, Java, or OpenGL ES. With this text I was up and running in a very short period and got some games done, which is always a great boost to keep going :)

Comment: Thanks, I have experience with unity 3d and c# [My Work!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5LGLL8cxB8) but I always wanted to create my own engine.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll also add that even though engine creation is very challenging and quite a bit different than game development, it is VERY rewarding. Good luck to you!

Answer (score -1):

COCOS2d is an open source framework for android and iphone and you will also found good tutorial for this framework.   Find here

[cocos2d-android](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/)

Comment: Cocos 2d is a game engine but i want to create my own...

Comment: OpernGL is a basic framwork which you can use. Basically Cocos2D is also build up on OpenGL.